# Apache is working but Mysql module not working on xampp v3.2.1 windows 7

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I had used xampp for my virtual server side program but suddenly i got an error message while I was trying to access phpmyadmin on my localhost. 
"Mysql said:#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." Then I re-install xampp and change the apache port from 80 to 8080 (because I am using Skype also) & I got the same mysql error [see the link](http://goo.gl/fvaJ8P) however Apache is running correctly... Please it would best if you help me out with that! thanks :)

Comment: Did you pressed the log button? And do you maybe block the port? Or doesn't the firewall allow the access from the network?

Comment: how do i know that the port is blocked or no and how to check the permission of the network in firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Please turn off the mysql service from administrative Tool -> services panel.